# Create model in rails console with association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have 2 models setup:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
end
```

I am now trying to create a topic with a category associated in the rails console:

```
t = Topic.new :name => "Test", :category => Category.find(1)
```

Trouble is the model has category_id, and so I'd need to use:

```
c = Category.find(1)
t = Topic.new :name => "Test", :category_id => c.id
```

But, I've seen many times the ability to simply use :category instead of :category_id and pass in the category object instead of the objects id. Where am I going wrong?

When I do:

```
c = Category.find(1)
t = Topic.new :name => "Test", :category => c
```

I receive:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: category
```

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.1.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to just do this:

```
c = Category.find(1)
t = Topic.new :name => "Test", :category => c
```

The association definition on the model is what lets you do this.

Interesting note, you can use :category_id and still just pass in the object, it will get the ID for you:

```
t = Topic.new :name => "Test", :category_id => c
```

Another way do do it which can be a bit nicer:

```
t = c.topics.build(:name => "Test") # Builds an object without saving

t = c.topics.create(:name => "Test") # Builds an object and saves it
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. When I do as in your first example I receive this error: "ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: category". My associations are setup as per my post. Thanks for the complimentary info too.

Comment: Do you get the same thing if you do the line t = c.topics.build(:name => "Test") ?

Comment: For that, I received "NoMethodError: undefined method `topics' for #<Category:0xaee5638>". On my migration I have used t.references :category when creating the table. I can't see where else I'd need to define this relationship.

Comment: The t.references :category should just create the category_id when creating the table, I believe.  This is very strange, can you show your whole model?

Comment: I know. Both models are as above (updated). Do I need to create an alias for category_id to become category?

Comment: Yes. All migrations created. I can create the model and association using :category_id = c, but just not :category.

Comment: Huh, sorry, I'm flummoxed.  All of the stuff I said worked fine in my environment...

Comment: No worries. Thanks very much for the help anyway. I'll let you know if I find out why so you can update your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: since you are doing a new, not a create, you could set the category after.  it t = Topic.new :name =>"test"; t.category = Category.first.  But since the topic belongs to the category I would build it through the association my self, ie c.topics.build(:name=>"test")

Comment: I would usually do that, although c.topics.build produces error as above in these comments. Not just that, there are many other associations this topic will carry, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an MRE of what worked for me

```
u = User.first

Trainer.create(name: "John", user: u)
```

Note that there's no 'user' column in the Trainer model, only user_id, yet when we `.create` the record in Trainer, we still use `user` (rails knows to place the id for that user in `user_id`)